# iOS OPENGL Texture GL_REPEAT repeats only two times

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a OpenGL program for iOS.

I would like to have a repeated texture. Normaly this is not a big deal for me, because GL_REPEAT does a fine job.

You can see the problem comparing the next two images:
First image is simulator screenshot. Everything works fine.
Second image is iPad screenshot. The textur will be repeated once and the clamped to edge.
Notice that the image is repeated 4 times in each direction. The red area is the area where the texture coordinate in a direction is > 1.0. So the device shows the image (normal area) repeats the image (red area) and than clamps the image.

[image: This is how it should look like and looks like in simulator]

[image: This is how it looks like on the device]

So I will show what I do to render the Quad.

I setup the texture

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

_location = location;

_texture = [self setupTextureByUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:name]];
_uniform = uniform;
```

The setUpTextureByUIImage function is

```
- (GLuint) setupTextureByUIImage: (UIImage*) image {
// We want to display images

glActiveTexture(_location);
GLuint texture;
// Generate textures
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
// Bind it
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);


// Get Image size
GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
// Allocate memory for image
void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 );
CGContextRef imgcontext = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
CGContextClearRect( imgcontext, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
CGContextTranslateCTM( imgcontext, 0, height - height );
CGContextDrawImage( imgcontext, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), image.CGImage );

// Generate texture in opengl
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
// Release context
CGContextRelease(imgcontext);
// Free Stuff
free(imageData);

return texture;
}
```

After setup I begin to draw an object.
First I call makeActiveAndBind.
Then I draw.
Then I call unbind.

```
    - (void) makeActiveAndBind
{
    glActiveTexture(_location);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glUniform1i(_uniform, _location - GL_TEXTURE0);
}

- (void) unbind
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea to this strange behavior?
The texture coordinates of the cube are [0,4]x[0,4]